# Vlook up in gawk or unix

Tags: linux

I would like to do a vlookup in unix or `gawk`.
I have a file with a column of numbers (file1)
I have a file with several columns (file2)
I want to look up for the numbers I have in file 1 into column one of file 2

I was using `grep -f file1 file2` but this prints all the lines in file two containing a string as in file 1, not just the lines that have the string in column one of file 2

How can I solve this with `gawk` or other unix tools?

Comment: What's a vlook up?

Answer (score 0):

```
while read vl ; do grep "^$vl " file2 ; done < file1
```

`read` looks for input terminated by a newline and places in the variable `vl`. By wrapping this in a `while` loop this is repeated for all contents of `STDIN`. By using `< file1` we redirect the contents of `file1` into STDIN, so the loop repeats for all contents of `file1`. For each line of `file1` (stored in `vl`) we grep in `file2` with the search term prefixed by `^`. This ties the search term to be at the beginning of the line in `file2`. I've also added a space at the end of the grep search string (I'm assuming file2's column separator is a space), so that it will only match exactly and not sub matches (if the search term is foo and `file2` has a row with foobar as column one it will *not* get matched). Replace that space with whatever your field separator of `file2` is if it is not space.

If you can change file1 at will then:

```
sed -i 's/^\(.*\)$/^\1 /' file1
```

and then your original `grep -f` will work (note again I've used space as a separator - after the `\1`).